# Should "at most four" have commas?

Tags: commas

I think it is natural to say the following:

> Every planar graph can be colored using at most four colors.

However, an editor told me to add commas, as follows:

> Every planar graph can be colored using, at most, four colors.

The commas seem awkward to me.  For example, I don't think you would insert them in a sentence using "at least."

> Every football team needs at least two linebackers.

Googling tells me that the use of "at most" without commas is fairly standard in mathematical writing (which is what I am doing). Is this convention considered correct in other contexts?

Comment: Editors, ignorant as may be, still have the final say-so

Comment: I would certainly include them. Only if the sentence is very simple indeed, so that no aid to clarification is required, do I omit such commas. 'Tiddles the cat died' probably doesn't need commas around 'the cat'.

Comment: I agree with you. Adding the commas only introduces complexity, slows the sentence down, and puts unnecessary emphasis on "at most".

Answer (score 1):

Take your pick. They are both correct, and they mean the same thing. But the connotations can be a bit different.

As others have noted, the commas can slow reading down. They can set apart (emphasize) *at most*, helping the reader to notice it. If that's important to you then you might want to add the commas here. If not, drop them.

In the case of the simple sentence you gave, I cannot imagine that it is important to you to emphasize **NOT MORE THAN** 4, except insofar as that might be important to your editor. ;-)

Also, if it is truly important then you probably do not want to depend on just those little commas to make the ***NOT MORE THAN*** point. If that is the main point of the central theorem of your thesis, then find a more explicit way to draw attention to it.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your two examples is in emphasis; the use of commas in the "at most, four" construction is meant to emphasize the "at most" element, and set it apart. Whatever the standards in mathematical writing may be, it would certainly be more readable to just stick the commas in.